# How can I drag and drop a date not event to outside the calendar in fullcalendar V2?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to choose some hours in Fullcalendar and drag it in another div for some things.

For instance, in the calendar I want to choose the hours and days where the teachers are free to tell studentabout it.

monday  at 8:00 am 2016-05-20

tuesday at 11:00 am 2016-05-21

friday at 04:00 pm 2016-05-24.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean with _choose some hours in fullcalendar and drag it in another div for some things_?! Give us an example if possible. Thanks!

Comment: example when an administrator want programming some hours to a teacher to study students .. he will click in every hours and day or drag and drop it to a div in the right of calendar to see what  he selected .. i  gave an example in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in FullCalendar plugin there is the select

```
select: function (start, end) {

  // Your logic

 }
```